# WYSIWYG do not make url when pasted in a hyperlink

Tags: 6, uri, wysiwyg

When I paste a URL into a TinyMCE editor using WYWIWYG it converts the text into a  link.

So `http://vimeo.com/18150336` would be come `<a href="http://vimeo.com/18150336">http://vimeo.com/18150336</a>`. I would like to keep the plain text. Is their a way to configure TinyMCE to keep the link as plain text.

I do not want to strip out  tags as adding a hyperlinks should be an option on the toolbar. It should just not happen by default.

Comment: Also in drupal 7 i try this module TinyMCE and there is this problem, i try to modify the settings of WYSIWYG , and i set "Unlink" then when i write the links in the editor I unlinked the links but don't right.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the solution--**
On drupal administration:

*Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats*

you must remove "**Converts URL into links**" and then all it's Right!!

Comment: That is Drupal 7. Also I don't think that will solve the issue. I can strip a tags out on the input filter on submit. That is fine. But I dont want to. I want to strip them out when you paste them in. Only in the WYSIWYG if you click th link button should something become a hyperlink. As I am allowing the link button I can not strip the tags out.

Comment: If you want to write with the editor the text:http://vimeo.com/18150336 you must disable the option "Converts URL into links" and you will make it.

Comment: The WYSIWYG still inserts is as a link. When I save it will be stripped out but that is not what I want. I don't want it to go in as a link.

Answer (score 0):

- In Drupal 6, go to admin/settings/filters/list
- Click "configure" for the type of input filter being used
- Uncheck "URL filter", then Save Configuration